# Somar os valores entre os dict

Tags: python, dicionário

**OBJETIVO:**

Estou tentando somar os valores entre os dict ct_db e ct_db2, sempre que as chaves forem iguais.

**Exemplo:**

RR-00 == RR-00, então faça 14 + 223

**Problema:**

Não está sendo comparado todas as chaves dos dict, a operação é finalizada assim que é percorrido uma vez os dict, mas como estão fora de ordem as chaves, não é feito os cálculos corretos

**SCRIPT:**

```
ct_db = {u'AB-00': 18, u'RR-00': 14, u'LD-00': 56, u'SR-00': 33, u'YT-00': 452}
ct_db2 = {u'CD-07': 26, u'RR-00': 223, u'LD-00': 367, u'SR-00': 257, u'IA-00': 11}

not_installed = []
for elemA, elemB in zip(ct_db, ct_db2):
        if(elemA == elemB):
                print("MATCH "+elemA+" - "+elemB)
                not_installed.append(ct_db[elemA] + ct_db2[elemB])
        else:
                print("NOT MATCH "+elemA+" - "+elemB)

print(not_installed)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
NOT MATCH LD-00 - CD-07
NOT MATCH SR-00 - LD-00
NOT MATCH AB-00 - RR-00
NOT MATCH RR-00 - IA-00
NOT MATCH YT-00 - SR-00
[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No código acima, voce compara sempre os valores de mesmo index do dict..
E se voce fizer algo parecido com isso?:

```
ct_db = {u'AB-00': 18, u'RR-00': 14, u'LD-00': 56, u'SR-00': 33, u'YT-00': 452}
ct_db2 = {u'CD-07': 26, u'RR-00': 223, u'LD-00': 367, u'SR-00': 257, u'IA-00': 11}

not_installed = []
for elemA in ct_db:
    if elemA in ct_db2:
        print("MATCH "+elemA)
        not_installed.append(ct_db[elemA] + ct_db2[elemA])
    else:
        print("NOT MATCH "+elemA)

print(not_installed)
```

Não deve ser a forma mais otimizada, mas acho que resolve

Comment: Mas já ajuda amigo, muito obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento!

Comment: Fiz uns ajustes no codigo, dê uma olhada depois.. Ficou um pouco mais simples

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Parece um bom uso pro `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

ct_db = {u'AB-00': 18, u'RR-00': 14, u'LD-00': 56, u'SR-00': 33, u'YT-00': 452}
ct_db2 = {u'CD-07': 26, u'RR-00': 223, u'LD-00': 367, u'SR-00': 257, u'IA-00': 11}

soma = Counter(ct_db) + Counter(ct_db2)
print(soma)
# Counter({'YT-00': 452, 'LD-00': 423, 'SR-00': 290, 'RR-00': 237, 'CD-07': 26, 'AB-00': 18, 'IA-00': 11})

# Também podemos obter um dicionário novamente
print(dict(soma))
# {'AB-00': 18, 'RR-00': 237, 'LD-00': 423, 'SR-00': 290, 'YT-00': 452, 'CD-07': 26, 'IA-00': 11}
```